# How to add tooltip when click on barchart in flutter

Tags: flutter, charts, flutter-layout

I use this library I wanted to display a tooltip when you click on the bar to display the value. or to display the value inside the bar
here is the code that displays the bar group. I wanted to display the sales value in a tooltip or display the sales value directly inside the bar

```
// Bar chart example
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

class GroupedBarChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  GroupedBarChart(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  factory GroupedBarChart.withSampleData() {
    return new GroupedBarChart(
      _createSampleData(),
      // Disable animations for image tests.
      animate: false,
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.BarChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: animate,
      barGroupingType: charts.BarGroupingType.grouped,
    );
  }

  /// Create series list with multiple series
  static List<charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>> _createSampleData() {
    


    final mobileSalesData = [
      new OrdinalSales('2014', 10),
      new OrdinalSales('2015', 15),
      new OrdinalSales('2016', 50),
      new OrdinalSales('2017', 45),
    ];

    return [
     
      new charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>(
        id: 'Mobile',
        domainFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: mobileSalesData,
      ),
    ];
  }
}

/// Sample ordinal data type.
class OrdinalSales {
  final String year;
  final int sales;

  OrdinalSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```

[image]

Comment: this package https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/gallery.html

Comment: did you try https://github.com/google/charts/issues/58 solutions?

Comment: i try not working for bar chart